# Day of week/Time of day restrictions for a .NET application

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Anyone have any ideas on a good way to model the following scenario in my domain/database for a .NET application? Let's say I have certain discounts that can be applied to sales transactions, but the discounts should only be applied on certain days of the week at certain times. So for example, if a sale occurs on Monday between the hours of 9AM and noon, the discount should be applied, but if a sale occurs on Tuesday between those hours, no discount is applied. I would like to be able to handle multiple time periods within the same day as well (ie - Wednesday from 9AM - noon and 6PM - midnight.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like homework.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: I don't know why you think that, but even if it's homework it doesn't change anything. He can still ask for advice on StackOverflow.

Comment: I just figured someone has had to implement something like this in the past and I certainly have ideas on how it can be done. I just wanted to see if there were some ideas that I had not thought about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar to this.

Your SalePrice table would look like (damn markdown tables):

**SalePriceId** Guid, PK
**ItemId**      Guid, FK
**StartTime**   Timespan
**EndTime**     Timespan
**DaysOfWeek**  DaysOfWeek (flag enum)
**Discount**    double

(This is from the code view; Timespan is a .NET class that maps in Sql 2008)

DaysOfWeek is a flag enum containing Sun-Sat.

So to find any sales for an item that are in effect on tuesday, you would do something like

```
select * 
from SalePrice
where ItemId = @itemGuid
and StartTime <= @time 
and EndTime >= @time
and DaysOfWeek & @DOW = @DOW
```

This is the basic pattern.  Don't expect this to copy-paste work (I'm not sure about my bitwise query stuff), but I'm using this pattern successfully to track current prices.

Comment: you should use the decimal type for Discount or (money in SQL)

Answer (score 1):

I would simply write a "GetDiscount" method that would implement the logic you are describing. You can use the DateTime object to determine current day and time.

From your description it is not clear why such simple solution wont work for you. What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: The days and time periods would need to be set up differently for each discount. So there will be a UI that allows and end user to specify the the days and time periods for each individual discount. So I need to persist those to the database along with the discount that they are tied to.

Answer (score 0):

I would just create the following two classes assuming you apply the discount to a comlete order, not single items.

```
class Order
{
    Guid Id;
    DateTime TimeStamp;
    Discount Discount;
}

class Discount
{
    Guid Id;
    DayOfWeek Day;
    TimeSpan StartTime;
    TimeSpan EndTime;
    Decimal Amount;
}
```

Then you can use `Order.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek` and `Order.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay` and search through a list of discounts until you find a `Discount` valid for the processed order and store a reference on the `Order` object. Mapping this to a database should be quite simple - `DayofWeek` can be stored as an integer, `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` are availiable, too.

The tricky part is constraining the one-to-many relationship between `Order` and `Discount`. One could try using triggers or check constraints, but I would suggest to enforce this logic only in the application because you don't gain that much by enforcing it at the database level.